# Ifile not getting uploaded in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying to upload a file in databse using codeigniter, the image is getting stored in the folder but i'm having issue in storing the data in databse, i don know where 
im going wrong. please can any one guide me what im doing wrong ? im new to codeigniter concept.

upload.php(controller)

```
    <?php

       class Upload extends CI_Controller {

          public function __construct() { 
             parent::__construct(); 
             $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
          }

          public function index() { 
             $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' )); 
          } 

          public function do_upload() { 
             $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
             $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
             $config['max_size']      = 100; 
             $config['max_width']     = 1024; 
             $config['max_height']    = 768;  
             $this->load->library('upload', $config);

             if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
             }

             else { 
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('filename'),$this->input->post()); 
                $this->Upload_model->saverecords($data);
                //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
             } 
          } 
       } 
    ?>
```

Upload_model.php(model)

```
    <?php
        class Upload_model extends CI_Model 
        {
            //Insert
            function saverecords($data)
            {
                //saving records
                $this->db->insert('latest_news', $data); 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Upload_form.php(view)

```
        <html>

       <head> 
          <title>Upload Form</title> 
       </head>

       <body> 
          <?php echo $error;?> 
          <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?> 

          <form action = "" method = "POST">
             <input type = "file" name = "filename" size = "20" /> 
             <br /><br /> 
             <input type = "submit" value = "upload" /> 
          </form> 

       </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: show your post `$this->input->post()` and add your post data individually in your `$data` variable

Comment: sir m new to this codeigniter please can u explain me by editing my code?

Comment: that is why i am asking to print `$this->input->post()`

Comment: Sorry sir im not getting u

Answer (score 0):

You declare `<form>` twice! Remove `<form action = "" method = "POST">` completely and just use the above `form_open_multipart`:

```
      <?php echo $error;?> 
      <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?> 
         <input type="file" name="filename" size="20" /> 
         <br /><br /> 
         <input type="submit" value="upload" /> 
      </form>
```

Also there is no need for spaces like `type = "submit"`

Then in your code:

```
         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
         }

         else { 
            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('filename'),$this->input->post());
            $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $this->load->model('upload_model');
            $this->upload_model->saverecords($data);
            //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
         }
```

---

For future:

Do not just do `$this->input->post()` to assign the key value pairs to those in db. It is not very controlled and can lead to issues. Instead just define it. So if you add other data it would look something like:

```
$data = array(
    'example1_fieldname' => $this->input->post('example1_fieldname');
    'upload_data' => $this->upload->data('file_name');
);
```

Comment: that is an example for the future. forget it for now until/if you add more inputs.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Upload::$Upload_model

Filename: controllers/Upload.php

Line Number: 30

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\controllers\Upload.php
Line: 30
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function saverecords() on null

Filename: controllers/Upload.php

Line Number: 30

Backtrace:

Comment: you need to load your model... you really should re-read ci docs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152531/error-in-storing-image-in-upload-folder

Comment: check this link sir