# error while trying to store the image in upload folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I'm trying this to get worked from morning but don't know why it is not working, the file which I upload is getting stored in the database but when I check my upload folder where I want to store my images their the images are not getting stored. please, can anyone tell me what problem I'm facing, please?

**Home.php**

```
    <?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Home extends CI_Controller {  

        public function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();

            //load database libray manually
            $this->load->database();

            //load Model
            $this->load->model('Contact_model');

            // load form and url helpers
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            // load form_validation library
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

         public function Latest_news()
        {  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_content', 'First content', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_content', 'Second content', 'required');
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )&&(!$this->upload->do_upload('filename')))
            {
                $this->load->view('Latest_news'); 
            }
            else
            {
                //insert
                $data = array();
                $data['first_content']=$this->input->post('first_content');
                $data['second_content']=$this->input->post('second_content');
                $data['filename']=$this->input->post('filename');  
                //Transfering data to Model
                $this->Contact_model->latest_news($data);
                //Redirecting to success page
                redirect(site_url('Home/Latest_news'));
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**Contact_model.php**

```
    <?php
        class Contact_model extends CI_Model 
        {
            function latest_news($data)
            {
            //saving records
            $this->db->insert('latest_news', $data); 
            }

        }   
    ?>
```

**Latest_news.php**

```
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <div style="padding-top:10%; padding-left:30%">
            <div>
                <textarea name="first_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <span><?php echo form_error("first_content");?></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <textarea name="second_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <span><?php echo form_error("second_content");?></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="filename">
                <span><?php echo form_error("filename");?></span>
            </div><br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: first, you need to user `<?= form_open_multipart('')?>`, then you never display the exact erros like `$this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');` and `validation_errors ();`

Comment: sir can u edit my code

Comment: use <`form action="Latest_news" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` instead of `<?php echo form_open(); ?>`. Then upload the file and test your request by using the `$_FILES['file']['filename']`, this will help you to identify the error etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in storing image in upload folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152531/error-in-storing-image-in-upload-folder)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. Your first question that is the same already has a valid answer. It is up to you to implement it correctly.

Comment: ok sir sure ....